# Running Selenium on Docker stuck at Started Selenium Standalone

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium inside a Docker container but after running the docker container the console stays stuck at

```
INFO [Standalone.execute] - Started Selenium Standalone 4.4.0 (revision e5c75ed026a): http://172.18.0.2:4444
```

The configuration is pretty simple as I'm trying to just take a screenshot of the web page. My files are

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    restart: always

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: sh -c "python3 bot.py"
    depends_on:
      - selenium
```

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
```

***python app***

```
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver

sleep(5)

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)

driver.get('https://python.org')
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

Selenium seems to run correctly as I got the message `INFO success: selenium-standalone entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)` and I'm able to reach `http://172.18.0.2:4444/ui#`

I've also noticed that if I let run enough time the container, it rise the following error

```
[urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.18.0.2', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session](urllib3.exceptions.maxretryerror: httpconnectionpool(host='172.18.0.2', port=4444): max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (caused by connecttimeouterror(<urllib3.connection.httpconnection object at 0x7f85ac015900>, 'connection to 172.18.0.2 timed out.)
```

Comment: I can start with you script and configuration both containers without a problem and it works as expected (i.e. screenshot taken and saved etc.). Is the screenshot is taken in you cases in /app? or what do you mean by "it stuck"?

Comment: @m19v yes here as well https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/1677 I added the timeout error that occurs later

Comment: If you mean, screenshot is made by yes, What is then the problem? Once you bot.py does what you need, you need to just stop the selenium standalone server which just serves as remote selenium driver.

Comment: no it doesn't work. As I explained, the execution stays stuck and no screenshot is taken